# time zone converter including daylight saving time

Tags: javascript

hi How to calculate the time zone value based on country name including daylight saving time. Please help me.

Comment: This will necessarily be somewhat approximate for countries spanning multiple time zones, like, say, the United States.

Comment: You'll need to find some database/library. There's no support for working with different timezones in js -- only with current user's one.

Comment: @kirilloid—not strictly true. Javascript Date objects have a `timezoneOffset` property and can work comfortably with local or UTC times to make calculations that take account of time zones. However, finding the time zone for a particular location does, as you say, require access to a suitable database of time zone offsets by geographic location and date (for daylight saving, where observed).

Comment: @RobG there's only `getTimezoneOffset()`. One can't event set it.

Comment: @kirilloid—true, but that isn't really a problem. Just work with UTC and convert to local time (or whatever suits) for display. `getTimezoneOffset` is only handy for finding out what it's set to on the current host, but means you can work in local or UTC or convert to any timezone. Setting the timezone offset (if possible) should not change the actual system timezone because more than one timezone may use the same offset (e.g. ADT and AMST are UTC - 3 hrs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a 3rd party library like [timezone-js](http://github.com/mde/timezone-js).